# As3 how to make a xmllist from each element of another xmllist

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

If I have a XMLList, FirstLevel:XMLList, from a xml:XML, than I can serialize like this:

```
var FirstLivel:XMLList = xml.children();
for(var i in FirstLevel){
```

I want the children from each item, like this:

```
SecondLevel:XMLList = FirstLevel[i].children();
```

But this doesn't work! What is the right way of get those children?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Do you get a compiler error, run time error, or it works but just not returning what you wanted?

Comment: I got a compiler error: "1188: Illegal assignment to class XMLList."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstLevel:XMLList = xml.children();
var secondLevel:Array = [];

for each (var child in firstLevel) {
    secondLevel.push(child);
}

trace(secondLevel[0]); // this gets you the first child
```

Comment: I almost forgot to mark this! I gess child is a new XML. My code is now working, but I didn't fully understand how it works, maybe with time!

Comment: Look the AS3 manual to understand what `for each` does. In this code it is putting every child of the `firstLevel` var in the `child` var on every loop.